# Why are my images hyper compressed in Webpack?

Tags: webpack

I'm using image-webpack-loader with file-loader. Despite I'm using a "90-100" indice on pngquant my png image are released ridiculously light and poor quality. Currently my png_background has 892 bytes ! and a so poor quality with theses above indices.

Here my config :

```
  // images
  {
    test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg)$/i,
    use: [
      'file-loader',
      {
        loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
        options: {
          mozjpeg: {
            progressive: true,
            quality: 65
          },
          // optipng.enabled: false will disable optipng
          optipng: {
            enabled: true,
          },
          pngquant: {
            quality: '90-100',
          },
          gifsicle: {
            interlaced: false,
          },
          // the webp option will enable WEBP
          webp: {
            quality: 75
          }
        }
      },
    ],
  }
```

I have tried to play with it a few but my image are still released hyper compressed. I'm wondering why that happen ? 
Any hint would be great,
thanks

Comment: when I'm meaning hyper compressed I mean with a poor image quality

Comment: Your JPEG quality setting is 65, which will cut the quality almost in half. Have you tried raising that?

Comment: Oups, I talked about my PNG image.  Despite I'm using a "90-100" indice on pngquant my png image are released ridiculously light and poor quality. Currently my png_background has 892 bytes ! and a so poor quality with theses above indices.